# Getting Request URL, Scheme, Hostname and Port in ServiceStack service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

Within ServiceStack service I'd like to be able to get the request HTTP Scheme (HTTP or HTTPS), hostname and port which I would then use to construct the absolute path for images that are being returned as an array (or list) of URLs.

Service runs within the ASP.NET MVC application (the side-by-side scenario at /api) but this could change in the future to self-hosted SS so if a solution that covers both scenarios exists it would be nice to have us implement it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every request or response filter or inside any ServiceStack Service you always have access to the underlying HTTP [Request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IHttpRequest.cs) and [Response](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IHttpResponse.cs). e.g. how to access them in your Service:

```
public class MyService : Service
{ 
    public object Get(Request request) 
    {
        var scheme = base.Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https" : "http";
        base.Response...
    }
}
```

If you ever need access to the underlying HTTP Request or Response you can always access them with:

```
var aspnetRequest = (HttpRequest) base.Request.OriginalRequest;
var aspnetResponse = (HttpResponse) base.Request.OriginalResponse;
```

#### Programmatically constructing URLs to Services

ServiceStack lets you construct relative or absolute urls for services by using the same in-built `ToUrl(method,format)` and `ToAbsoluteUrl(method,format)` extension methods that the C# Service Clients use:

```
[Route("/customers")]
[Route("/customers/{Id}")]
public class Customers : IReturn<List<Customer>>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

Given the above Request DTO and defined routes, you can construct the following urls which will use the most relevant url to create the url, e.g:

```
var relativeUrl = new Customers().ToUrl(); // /customers
var absoluteUrl = new Customers().ToAbsoluteUri(); // http://host/api/customers

// /customers/1
var relativeIdUrl = new Customers { Id = 1 }.ToUrl();  
// http://host/api/customers/1
var absoluteIdUrl = new Customers { Id = 1 }.ToAbsoluteUri();
```

Comment: ToAbsoluteUrl is actually ToAbsoluteUri